# Get rid of empty grid spaces

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've setup a two element grid in Bootstrap, each element has some hidden content in it. Clicking the title toggles it.

The only problem is that expanding it causes all the other items to rearrange and leaves massive white spaces.

Any suggestions on:
1. How to avoid these whitespaces
2. Maybe disable the rearranging?

All collapsed
[image]

Expanded element
[image]

Comment: like this way https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/9cuonLa9/

Comment: Thanks but it seems that fiddle suffers from the same problem

Comment: ya...i think it is difficult to achieve..